# What does Joint.Position refer to?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm trying to detect certain positions or gestures of the user using Kinect and the Kinect SDK 1.8. For this purpose I intend to use the information provided by the `Joint.Position` attribute. However, I can't make sense of the values I'm reading. What do they mean? Are they the distance between the joint and the sensor? What unit are they being measured with?

Comment: Haven't used the SDK in a while, but should be a vector with 3 components (X,Y,Z): positions relative to the sensor(the IR cam I'll guess) and units are mm. To test, print out the position of a joint (e.g. one of your hands), move it slowly towards and away from the sensor: Z (depth) should change, then repeat for X or Y axis to get an idea of data you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Joint.Position` is a 3D vector which contains `X`, `Y` and `Z` properties. Each of these properties represents the **distance in meters** (along the X, Y and Z directions) of the joint from the origin of the coordinate system used.

In Microsoft Kinect SDK 1.8, the coordinate system is centered on the Kinect sensor, and the following image explains how it is defined:

[image: Kinect coordinate system]

Take a look to the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973078.aspx) and [this post on MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9725f685-5839-43db-b13d-aa9afcf1b7a5/units-of-values-of-jointposition?forum=kinectsdk) if you need more details.