# What is (X, Y) value in Kinect's Skeleton Joint.Position. (X,Y, Z)?

Tags: kinect, tracking, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

I tried this

```
Joint rightHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];

double rightX = rightHand.Position.X;
double rightY = rightHand.Position.Y;
double rightZ = rightHand.Position.Z;
```

then I got this :

```
rightX : 0,04908288
rightY : -0,0657815
rightZ : 1,776147
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEvIF.png)

Can anyone explain to me, what is X and Y value?
I heard that the range of that value will be from -1 to 1.
Is the value of 'rightHand.Position.Z' same as the Z-axis value of the Object? Or it represents the object's distance from the center of the 3D coordinate system (0,0,0) which is I may say Z'? Because when I move my head up and down 'rightHand.Position.Z' value increases higher. However, it decreases when I move my head horizontally with XZ plane.

Due to I need to obtain the angle between the line Z' and the XZ plane (the angle between Z' and its orthogonal projection onto XZ), I want somebody to explain what is X and Y?

PS: XZ plane is the plane between X-axis and Z-axis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does Joint.Position refer to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102243/what-does-joint-position-refer-to)

Answer (score 2):

The `Position` property is a 3D vector which contains `X`, `Y` and `Z` properties. Each of these properties represents the **distance in meters** (along the X, Y and Z directions) of the joint from the origin of the coordinate system used.

In Microsoft Kinect SDK, the coordinate system is centered on the Kinect sensor, and the following image explains how it is defined:

[image: Kinect coordinate system]

Take a look to the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973078.aspx) and [this post on MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9725f685-5839-43db-b13d-aa9afcf1b7a5/units-of-values-of-jointposition?forum=kinectsdk) if you need more details.

Comment: thank you @Vito Gentile, I want to confirm something in this question actually but I couldn't make it clear, let me explain with a picture.